# Plotting two subgroups of several groups against one another, when in long format

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
#data
set.seed(1)
data_foo <- data.frame(id = rep(LETTERS[1:4], times = 2), group_measure = c(rep('a_c',4),rep('b_c',4), c(rep('a_d',4),rep('b_d',4))),
                       value = sample(1:5, size = 16, replace = TRUE))
```

I would like to plot the 'a' subgroups on the x axis against the 'b' subgroups on the y axis, and one plot for each measure. 
Like this:

```
require(tidyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(patchwork)

data_foo_long <- data_foo %>% spread( group_measure, value)

p1 <- ggplot(data_foo_long, aes(x = a_c, y = b_c)) +
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(data_foo_long, aes(x = a_d, y = b_d)) +
  geom_point()
p1 + p2
```

[image]

I don't see a way with faceting (?).
But I have the impression that there must be a better, more ggplot-like way of plotting the outcomes of two subgroups within a group against one another when I have them in a long format. Needless to say - there are more measures than those two.

---

P.S. if someone has a suggestion for a better title of this question, please feel free to comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way. How well it works with "more measures" I will leave to you to decide.

Use `tidyr::separate` to split the group_measure into a prefix and a suffix, then spread on the prefix:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_foo %>% 
  separate(group_measure, 
           into = c("prefix", "suffix"), 
           sep = "_") %>% 
  spread(prefix, value)

  id suffix a b
1  A      c 2 2
2  A      d 4 4
3  B      c 2 5
4  B      d 1 2
5  C      c 3 5
6  C      d 2 4
7  D      c 5 4
8  D      d 1 3
```

Now you can plot `a` versus `b`, faceted by suffix:

```
data_foo %>% 
  separate(group_measure, 
           into = c("prefix", "suffix"), 
           sep = "_") %>% 
  spread(prefix, value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(a, b)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~suffix)
```

[image]

Comment: This works indeed for multiple groups! Thanks for your help - very neat :)